# Function not returning value at all - not a void

Tags: c

I have this function that is not returning a function value. I've added some random testers to try and debug but no luck. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 100

float error(int a, int b); 

int main(){
    printf("START\n");

    srand(time(NULL)); 

    int a, b, j, m;
    float plot[N+1]; 

    printf("Lower bound for x: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    printf("Upper bound for x: ");
    scanf("%d", &b); 

    printf("okay\n");

    for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
        plot[j] = 0; 

    printf("okay1\n");

    m = error(a,b);
    printf("%f\n",m);

    return 0; 
}

float error(int a, int b){
    float product = a*b;
    printf("%f\n",product);
    return product; 
}
```

so the `m = error(a,b)` always gives 0 no matter what!

Please help. I apologise for not cleaning this up...

Comment: To return `0` is not the same as not returning a value.

Comment: The question is off-topic for Programmers.SE, because it is about a specific coding problem. I expect it to be migrated to StackOverflow, where it belongs, in a short while.

Comment: Hints: Why are you returning float type from integer multiplication in float error...? Why assign a float value to integer value in m=error(a,b)? How can you be sure that both a and b are non-zero (try to print the value inside your function).

Answer (score 2):

This is because you declared `m` as `int`. Declare it as `float` and cast `a*b` to `float` because `a` and `b` are also `int`s. Another way is change the return type of your function to `int`;

```
int error(int a, int b){
int product = a*b;
printf("%f\n",product);
return product; 
}
```

and print `m` and `product` with `%d` specifier. Also do not forgot to change you function prototype in latter case.

Comment: actually, it would work as it is now if he just used %d properly

Answer (score 1):

```
int m;
m = error(a,b);
printf("%f\n",m);
```

You are trying to display *m* as *float* while it is *int*.

This shoud be:

```
m = error(a,b);
printf("%d\n",m);
```

My advice: stick to *ints* for now.

I think we have misunderstanding of how types work in C. It's not like in PHP that a variable can hold an int, then a float and some time later some string. In C variables are like steel buckets. They can change content, but never their shape. If you assign a *float* to an *int*, the floating point value will be converted into a integer value. Once you declare *m* as *int*, it will remain *int* to the end of it's life, capable of holding only *int* values.